# Magento 2 PWA Venia No definition MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL error

Tags: magento2, pwa

I install venia store and upward and all then start `yarn build` and all things looks good but when i try access website i get {"error":"No definition for env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL"}, I set it MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL in .env file .

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1**
Build Venia dist directory

```
yarn venia build
```

**Step 2**

Go to Venia dist directoy

```
cd packages/venia-concept/dist
```

**Step 3**
remove created upward.yml

```
rm upward.yml
```

**Step 4**

Add below upward.yml file

```
veniaResponse:
  resolver: conditional
  when:
    - matches: request.url.pathname
      pattern: ^/(graphql|rest|media)(/|$)
      use: veniaProxy
    - matches: request.url.pathname
      pattern: ^/(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|manifest\.json)
      use: staticFromRoot
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: (js|json|png|svg|ico|css|txt)
      use: veniaStatic
  default: veniaAppShell
staticFromRoot:
  inline:
    status: 200
    headers:
      resolver: inline
      inline:
        content-type: contentTypeFromExtension
    body:
      resolver: file
      parse:
        inline: text
      encoding:
        inline: binary
      file:
        resolver: template
        engine: mustache
        provide:
          filename: request.url.pathname
        template:
          resolver: inline
          inline: './venia-static/{{ filename }}'
contentTypeFromExtension:
  when:
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: ^ico$
      use:
        inline: image/x-icon
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: ^txt$
      use:
        inline: text/plain
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: ^json$
      use:
        inline: application/json
  default:
    inline: text/html
fileExtension:
  resolver: conditional
  when:
    - matches: request.url.pathname
      pattern: \.(.*)$
      use: $match.$1
  default:
    inline: ''
veniaProxy:
  resolver: proxy
  target: env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL
  ignoreSSLErrors:
    when:
      - matches: env.NODE_ENV
        pattern: production
        use:
          inline: false
    default:
      inline: true
veniaAppShell:
  resolver: inline
  inline:
    status:
      resolver: inline
      inline: 200
    headers:
      resolver: inline
      inline:
        content-type:
          inline: text/html
    body:
      resolver: file
      file:
        resolver: inline
        inline: ./index.html
veniaStatic:
  resolver: directory
  directory:
    resolver: inline
    inline: .
veniaTemplateIncludes:
  resolver: directory
  directory:
    resolver: inline
    inline: ./templates
veniaStaticIncludes:
  resolver: directory
  directory:
    resolver: inline
    inline: ./venia-static
status: veniaResponse.status
headers: veniaResponse.headers
body: veniaResponse.body
```

Comment: It works! But why is the initial upward.yml not working ?

Comment: I think Magento 2 PWA default bug with builded upward.yml.

Comment: Yes, strange but this one working for me as well.

Comment: i've have these text were echo {{#pageTypeNonce}}{{#webpackChunks}}{{/webpackChunks}} {{/pageTypeNonce}} in footer